# Efficiently match table of regex to a string

Tags: regex, string

Typically, you have a regular expression and lots of strings to process.

I have the opposite. I have one string, and I want to find all the regular expressions that match it. Let's say I have 10 million regular expressions. I'm not trying to do any replacement or rewriting of the string, I just want to find things that match.

I'd like to store these in a database. A crude way to do this would be to select all ten million lines and iterate through them. For each iteration, apply the regex and somehow (I'm a little unclear on this piece too) see if it matches. Perhaps my regex library has a function which I give it a string and a regex, and it tells me if it matches. If it does, then I print out the regex.

This would be slow. I'm wondering if I can somehow hand this off to a database, so that it just returns me a table of the regular expressions that match a given string, out of its table of 10 million.

I'm agnostic on the database used, I'd just like it to be fast. I don't need it to be "custom assembler" fast but just "let the database figure it out so I don't have to iterate on 10 million lines" fast.

Comment: 1. Why? 2. There is no limit to the number of regexes that could be construed for a simple string. `foobar` could be matched by `/.*/`, `/.*.*/`, `/.*.*.*/`, `/.*.*.*.*/` `...` you get the picture.

Comment: No, you will definitely need to look at every single regular expression (iterate all 1e7 lines). However, if they form some pattern which you are able to detect you might not need to *execute* every of them. So, what do the regexes look like, are they completely random?

Comment: surely the DB still has to test the string against all 1M regexes, so you're not being more efficient, only transferring the load from the client to the server. Only obvious optimisation is parallelisation which should be trivial for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I can somehow hand this off to a database, so that it just returns me a table of the regular expressions that match a given string

At least mysql can do this:

```
SELECT regex FROM table_with_regexes WHERE
      regex REGEXP someString;
```

Also it would be helpful if you tell us more about your actual problem. I don't think you wrote ten millions regexes by hand, they must have been automatically generated - tell us how.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would process in three steps:

#### Step 1 : Find a first sql query

Build a sql query that search for the regex matching my string.
*I would start with a small regex set for building the sql query.*

#### Step 2 : Refine it if nessary

Add more regexes and see how the sql query performs.
*I would optimize, rewrite it if necessary here.*

#### Step 3 : Use choosed database optimization tools

I would simply fine tune my sql query to respond as quickly as possible.
*I would use hints for the sql engine, indices, parallel executions etc*

Handing off all the hard work to the database is a good approach since IMO it's an elegant and clear approach.